# Unable load images into view pager fragment using picasso?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, picasso

My app crashes when I try to load images into imageview. I tried to get it work but it's not working. Error log is

```html
 --------- beginning of crash
2018-11-14 20:33:25.029 2520-2520/com.example.suraj.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.suraj.myapplication, PID: 2520
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:682)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
        at com.example.suraj.myapplication.SecondFragment.onCreateView(SecondFragment.java:22)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1676)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
```

I am using viewpager and created three fragments to load images from url into imageview.
Firstfragment.java is as

```html
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootview2=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag,container,false);
        ImageView ig2=(ImageView)rootview2.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DsdfsdfR.png").into(ig2);
        container.addView(rootview2);

        return rootview2;
    }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

        SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity.java is as

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES=3;
private ViewPager mpager;
private PagerAdapter mPageradapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mpager.setAdapter(new ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    }


    private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);

        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int positon) {
            switch (positon){
                case 0:return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1:return  SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 2");
                case 3:return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment,Instance 3");
                default:return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment,Instance 3");

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }


}
```

This app crashes with the logs I already uploaded

Answer (score -1):

```
**First thing you have to check whether you passing url in image is blank or not you should apply null check.and try with code like below code.**

 String url=propertyModels.get(getArguments().getInt("position")).imageurl;
             Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url).into(imageview);
```

Comment: propertymodels is unresolved. And also I have to add this code to fragment ? or mainactivity.java